# How to calculate whether two different objects have elements which intersect in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, intersection

I have two object arrays;

```
namesArr[col][row]     = new names("String",x,y); //Text Array

rectangleArr[col][row] = new rectangle(x,y); //awt.Rectangle Array
```

I simply want to identify the points where both elements exist, **not whether the elements' contents are equal.** For example, when comparing the points of intersection with sample data:

```
namesArr[0][1]= new names("Myname",1,2)
namesArr[0][2]= NULL
namesArr[3][4]= new names("notMyname",4,6)

rectangleArr[0][1] = new recatngle(7,8)
```

The algorithm should return that only one intersection exists at [0][1].

Comment: double for loop and check both Arr[i][j] is not null...?

Comment: What's a _recatngle_? And why is there an intersection at `[0][1]`? And what does _intersection_ mean for arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I generally vote with @Ben on this. However, if this must be done, and it must be done efficiently, I think you should switch from arrays to maps:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Map<Point,String> names=new HashMap<>();
        Map<Point,Rectangle> rectangles=new HashMap<>();

        names.put(new Point(0,1), "my name");
        names.put(new Point(0,2), null);
        names.put(new Point(1,4), "not my name");
        rectangles.put(new Point(0,1),new Rectangle(7, 8));

        //find matches 
        for(Point i:names.keySet()){
            if(rectangles.containsKey(i)){
                System.out.println("intersection at "+i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should get you well under the n^2 runtime of the arrays approach.

Here is a util function which includes David Conrad's optimization:

```
public static <Key> Set<Key> getIntersectingKeys(Map<Key, ?> map1, Map<Key, ?> map2) {
    Set<Key> ret, other;
    if (map1.size() < map2.size()) {
        ret = new HashSet<>(map1.keySet());
        other = map2.keySet();
    } else {
        ret = new HashSet<>(map2.keySet());
        other = map1.keySet();
    }
    Iterator<Key> it = ret.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Key i = it.next();
        if (!other.contains(i)) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I was going to use something different than for loops, but since the question seems very simple, I imagine the person who's asking doesn't have much knowledge in Java =S
I'm voting in yours, though.

Comment: You could improve it by checking the `size()` of each map first, and looping over the smaller of the two maps, checking for "intersections" in the other map.

Comment: @DavidConrad Updated with an example impl using your optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> intersections = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int namesArrCounter = 0; namesArrCounter < namesArr.length; namesArrCounter++ ){
    for(int namesArrColCounter = 0; namesArrColCounter < namesArr[namesArrCounter].length; namesArrColCounter++){

        if(namesArrCounter < rectangleArr.length && namesArrColCounter < rectangleArr[namesArrCounter].length){
            if(rectangleArr[namesArrCounter][namesArrColCounter] != null){
                intersections.add("["+namesArrCounter+"]"+"["+ namesArrColCounter +"]");
            }
        }

    }
}

return intersections;
```